# VBA: printing on the last row of excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am planning to extract data from a table on the web. The code below was mostly from built-in web scraping function in Excel.

What I want is to find the last row with data and print on the first blank row.

```
Sub Sub1()

ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 2

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http://www.aastocks.com/tc/stocks/quote/symbolsearch.aspx?page=" & i & " &order=symbol&seq=asc", Destination _
    :=Range("A,lastRow")) '???? I got an error here, what I want is to detect the last row and print on the first blank row.???
    '.CommandType = 0
    .Name = "symbolsearch_1"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebTables = "10"
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

Debug.Print lastRow
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work ok now. You were close, you should be able to edit as required.

```
Sub Sub1()

ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim sTicker As String

'set the first row to write to
lastRow = 2

For i = 1 To 2
sTicker = InputBox("Enter the code to search for")
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http://www.aastocks.com/tc/stocks/quote/symbolsearch.aspx?page=" & sTicker & " &order=symbol&seq=asc", Destination _
    :=Range("A" & lastRow)) 'uses the ticker value entered and fixed the destination part
    '.CommandType = 0
    .Name = "symbolsearch_1"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebTables = "10"
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

Next i

End Sub
```